# Repeat gt column labels on each page

Tags: r, pandoc, gt, quarto

I am using [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) with the `gt` R package to produce long tables of data and can't figure out how to get the column headers to appear at the top of each page in the PDF output.

For example `table.qmd`:

````
---
title: "Random Table"
format:
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false

library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

random <- tibble(
  id = seq(1:50),
  random = runif(50)
)

gt(random)
```
````

When rendered to PDF output (`quarto render table.qmd --to pdf`) The column header (id, random) only appears on the first page. The top of the second page looks like this:

[image: second page, no column header]

I can edit the TeX document, adding `\endhead` after the column header, and I get the result I want on the second (and subsequent) pages.

```
   158 \begin{longtable}{rr}
   159 \toprule
   160 id & random \\
   161 \midrule
+  162 \endhead
```

Like this:

[image: second page, with column header]

One option to add the `\endhead` would be to use a Pandoc filter to add the extra longtable command, but that sounds like a lot of effort for something so basic.

Is there a simple way with this workflow (Quarto options, pandoc, `gt`) to get column headers on each page in the PDF output?

Comment: ```GT``` package still hasn't this feature. Look [here:](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/194)

Comment: @manro Thanks, yeah I saw that issue. What I'm looking for seems so simple (add `\endhead` after the column heading in the `longtable` environment) that I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: FYI, I submitted this as a feature request to `gt`: [Repeating headers and/or column labels on multiple pages (LaTeX output)](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1061).

Comment: It will be cool if he adds this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem for my documents using pandoc filters. I'm still hoping there is a more elegant solution or that this is a feature that could be added to `gt`, but here's what I did.

Add the filter to the `pdf` section of the YAML header:

```yaml
format:
  pdf:
    filters:
      - endhead.lua
```

And here's the `endhead.lua` filter:

```lua
function RawBlock(elem)
    -- print(elem.text)
    return {
        pandoc.RawInline(
            "latex",
            string.gsub(
              elem.text, 
              "\\toprule\n(.-)\\midrule\n",
              "\\toprule\n%1\\midrule\n\\endhead\n"
            )
        ),
    }
end
```

`gt` within an R code block produces a `RawBlock` element in Pandoc's AST, so that's what needs to be changed using the filter. You can figure out the element you need to manipulate by adding `keep-md: true` to the YAML header of your Quarto doc, then after rendering, do:

```bash
$ pandoc -s -t native tables.md
```

That will show you the AST.

Once you know the Pandoc element, it's just a question of figuring out the regular expression that will add an `\endhead` element to the proper section of the table. I did this by finding the first `\midrule` after `\toprule` in each RawBlock (`gt` table). It took a bit for me to figure out how to use non-greedy capturing (`(.-)`) in order to only add `\endhead` once, right after the header of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a topical issue.

So, I can suggest a next one solution.

---

As you know - we can represent our gt table as a LaTeX code: https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/as_latex.html

Returning to your example **(!do it into console!):**

```
library(gt)
library(tibble)

random <- tibble(
    id = seq(1:50),
    random = runif(50)
)

gt(random) %>% 
    as_latex() %>%
    as.character()
```

Now we see our tab in next way (a lot of LaTeX code, which we should copy):

```
[1] "\\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt}\n\\begin{longtable}{rr}\n\\toprule\nid & random \\\\ \n\\midrule\n1 & 0.83452294 \\\\ \n2 & 0.43130524 \\\\ \n3 & 0.38702311 \\\\ \n4 & 0.75589167 \\\\ \n5 & 0.34432672 \\\\ \n6 & 0.75283676 \\\\ \n7 & 0.72770533 \\\\ \n8 & 0.20232485 \\\\ \n9 & 0.07900835 \\\\ \n10 & 0.80229610 \\\\ \n11 & 0.03800323 \\\\ \n12 & 0.03144921 \\\\ \n13 & 0.87364981 \\\\ \n14 & 0.47587592 \\\\ \n15 & 0.56736249 \\\\ \n16 & 0.83990532 \\\\ \n17 & 0.64138659 \\\\ \n18 & 0.76073451 \\\\ \n19 & 0.66013426 \\\\ \n20 & 0.54178832 \\\\ \n21 & 0.70443849 \\\\ \n22 & 0.81238956 \\\\ \n23 & 0.11305811 \\\\ \n24 & 0.12530444 \\\\ \n25 & 0.22497031 \\\\ \n26 & 0.35093560 \\\\ \n27 & 0.91268645 \\\\ \n28 & 0.19127469 \\\\ \n29 & 0.21638115 \\\\ \n30 & 0.24333619 \\\\ \n31 & 0.21178737 \\\\ \n32 & 0.50896038 \\\\ \n33 & 0.30918302 \\\\ \n34 & 0.44719810 \\\\ \n35 & 0.20445296 \\\\ \n36 & 0.67448123 \\\\ \n37 & 0.78824962 \\\\ \n38 & 0.62888684 \\\\ \n39 & 0.39583956 \\\\ \n40 & 0.99218439 \\\\ \n41 & 0.27330819 \\\\ \n42 & 0.20861772 \\\\ \n43 & 0.67226113 \\\\ \n44 & 0.11676375 \\\\ \n45 & 0.24479000 \\\\ \n46 & 0.28968861 \\\\ \n47 & 0.72271636 \\\\ \n48 & 0.58395987 \\\\ \n49 & 0.74914347 \\\\ \n50 & 0.32712809 \\\\ \n\\bottomrule\n\\end{longtable}\n"
```

Nice. Now we can transfer to our **qmd-file:**

````
---
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: article
    keep-tex: true
include-in-header:
- \usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, caption, longtable}
---


```{r, results='asis', echo=F}

k <- "\\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt}\n\\begin{longtable}{rr}\n\\toprule\nid & random \\\\ \n\\midrule\n1 & 0.83452294 \\\\ \n2 & 0.43130524 \\\\ \n3 & 0.38702311 \\\\ \n4 & 0.75589167 \\\\ \n5 & 0.34432672 \\\\ \n6 & 0.75283676 \\\\ \n7 & 0.72770533 \\\\ \n8 & 0.20232485 \\\\ \n9 & 0.07900835 \\\\ \n10 & 0.80229610 \\\\ \n11 & 0.03800323 \\\\ \n12 & 0.03144921 \\\\ \n13 & 0.87364981 \\\\ \n14 & 0.47587592 \\\\ \n15 & 0.56736249 \\\\ \n16 & 0.83990532 \\\\ \n17 & 0.64138659 \\\\ \n18 & 0.76073451 \\\\ \n19 & 0.66013426 \\\\ \n20 & 0.54178832 \\\\ \n21 & 0.70443849 \\\\ \n22 & 0.81238956 \\\\ \n23 & 0.11305811 \\\\ \n24 & 0.12530444 \\\\ \n25 & 0.22497031 \\\\ \n26 & 0.35093560 \\\\ \n27 & 0.91268645 \\\\ \n28 & 0.19127469 \\\\ \n29 & 0.21638115 \\\\ \n30 & 0.24333619 \\\\ \n31 & 0.21178737 \\\\ \n32 & 0.50896038 \\\\ \n33 & 0.30918302 \\\\ \n34 & 0.44719810 \\\\ \n35 & 0.20445296 \\\\ \n36 & 0.67448123 \\\\ \n37 & 0.78824962 \\\\ \n38 & 0.62888684 \\\\ \n39 & 0.39583956 \\\\ \n40 & 0.99218439 \\\\ \n41 & 0.27330819 \\\\ \n42 & 0.20861772 \\\\  \n43 & 0.67226113 \\\\ \n44 & 0.11676375 \\\\ \n45 & 0.24479000 \\\\ \n46 & 0.28968861 \\\\ \n47 & 0.72271636 \\\\ \n48 & 0.58395987 \\\\ \n49 & 0.74914347 \\\\ \n50 & 0.32712809 \\\\ \n\\bottomrule\n\\end{longtable}\n"

knitr::asis_output(k)

```
````

About `asis_output` look [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/knitr/man/asis_output.html)

**Output1:**

We see that this break between 43 and 44.
[image]

Considering the place for the header - updating our code (adding `\\toprule\nid & random \\\\ \n\\midrule` between 42 and 43:

**New code:**

````
---
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: article
    keep-tex: true
include-in-header:
- \usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, caption, longtable}
---


```{r, results='asis', echo=F}

k <- "\\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt}\n\\begin{longtable}{rr}\n\\toprule\nid & random \\\\ \n\\midrule\n1 & 0.83452294 \\\\ \n2 & 0.43130524 \\\\ \n3 & 0.38702311 \\\\ \n4 & 0.75589167 \\\\ \n5 & 0.34432672 \\\\ \n6 & 0.75283676 \\\\ \n7 & 0.72770533 \\\\ \n8 & 0.20232485 \\\\ \n9 & 0.07900835 \\\\ \n10 & 0.80229610 \\\\ \n11 & 0.03800323 \\\\ \n12 & 0.03144921 \\\\ \n13 & 0.87364981 \\\\ \n14 & 0.47587592 \\\\ \n15 & 0.56736249 \\\\ \n16 & 0.83990532 \\\\ \n17 & 0.64138659 \\\\ \n18 & 0.76073451 \\\\ \n19 & 0.66013426 \\\\ \n20 & 0.54178832 \\\\ \n21 & 0.70443849 \\\\ \n22 & 0.81238956 \\\\ \n23 & 0.11305811 \\\\ \n24 & 0.12530444 \\\\ \n25 & 0.22497031 \\\\ \n26 & 0.35093560 \\\\ \n27 & 0.91268645 \\\\ \n28 & 0.19127469 \\\\ \n29 & 0.21638115 \\\\ \n30 & 0.24333619 \\\\ \n31 & 0.21178737 \\\\ \n32 & 0.50896038 \\\\ \n33 & 0.30918302 \\\\ \n34 & 0.44719810 \\\\ \n35 & 0.20445296 \\\\ \n36 & 0.67448123 \\\\ \n37 & 0.78824962 \\\\ \n38 & 0.62888684 \\\\ \n39 & 0.39583956 \\\\ \n40 & 0.99218439 \\\\ \n41 & 0.27330819 \\\\ \n42 & 0.20861772 \\\\ \\toprule\nid & random \\\\ \n\\midrule \n43 & 0.67226113 \\\\ \n44 & 0.11676375 \\\\ \n45 & 0.24479000 \\\\ \n46 & 0.28968861 \\\\ \n47 & 0.72271636 \\\\ \n48 & 0.58395987 \\\\ \n49 & 0.74914347 \\\\ \n50 & 0.32712809 \\\\ \n\\bottomrule\n\\end{longtable}\n"

knitr::asis_output(k)

```
````

**The desired output:**

[image]

---

So, the main idea of this method: **first render of qmd-file -> detect the break -> manually add the header.**

Comment: That seems much harder than using the `keep-tex: true` header option, adding `\endhead` to the table in the TeX file, then rendering the entire document with `xelatex`. Both require manual fiddling that we shouldn’t need to perform, but at least the `keep-tex` method doesn’t require manually determining the table page break (or many breaks if the table takes up several pages).

Answer (score 0):

Since we only need to add the `\endhead` after the `\midrule`, one option could be inserting `\endhead` after the `\midrule` (Using the answer from @manro),

````
---
title: "Random Table"
format:
  pdf:
    keep-tex: true
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| results: asis

library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

random <- tibble(
  id = seq(1:50),
  random = runif(50)
)

t <- gt(random) %>%
  as_latex() %>%
  as.character()

knitr::asis_output(gsub("(.*\\\\begin\\{longtable\\}.*?\\midrule\\\n)", t, replacement = "\\1\\\\endhead\\\n"))
```
````

---

[image]

---

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I managed to get a Pandoc filter to do something very similar, just at a different point in the process from Quarto to PDF. The more I look at this, the more I think it's probably something that `gt` should be doing if requested, since it's generating the raw TeX code being passed straight through Pandoc.